# Checking command line argument in PHP

Tags: php

I want to pass two different arguments to my script and based on the sent argument, I need my script does something.But I don't know how to define my conditional statement.

To be more precise, I want my script does searching when I pass "search" argument and alternatively showing the result when I pass "show" argument.

Here is my code:

```
if ($argc > 1) {
  if ($argv[0] == 'show') {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $argv[2]; $i++) {
      //do something
    }
  }
  elseif($argv[0] == 'search') {
    //do something
  }
} else {
  echo "no argument passed\n";
}
```

The "IF" statement is not checking my passing argument whether it is "search" or "show"

Comment: try to use `else if`.

Comment: That also does not work.

Comment: Isn't $argv[0] the script name?

Comment: how you execute this program in command line ?

Comment: The if statement is not checking the passing arguments...

Comment: @AydinHassan No the script name is something different like "test"

Comment: To parse command line options, you should use `getopt`, see [documntation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php)

Comment: @BabakKhoramdin: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: @Gunslinger_ like this: php script.php show 10   or php script.php search keyword

Comment: See [getopt()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php).

Comment: aydin-hassan is right, $argv[0] contains the name of script. You should check $argv[1] for first argument value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$argv[0]` is the name of the script, that's why your code doesn't work.

If I have a file script.php:

```
<?php
if ($argc > 1) {
  if ($argv[1] == 'show') {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $argv[2]; $i++) {
      print "show passed\n";
    }
  }
  elseif($argv[1] == 'search') {
    print "search passed";
  }
} else {
  echo "no argument passed\n";
}
```

Testing gives:

```
$php script.php
```

> no argument passed

```
$php script.php search
```

> search passed

```
$php script.php show 2

show passed
show passed
show passed
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not?

```
$aPassedOptions = getopt("", ['show', 'search']);
$bShow = isset($aPassedOptions['show']);
$bSearch = isset($aPassedOptions['search']);
var_dump($aPassedOptions, $bShow, $bSearch);


script.php --show
script.php --search
script.php --show --search
```

more @ http://www.php.net/getopt  (for example, paramter is required etc)

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `switch/case` instead and your condition (`$argc`) is wrong as you you need action name and argument and `$argv[0]` is script name, so your `command` is `argv[1]` and its arguments `argv[2]` and up. I'd also get `argc/argv` from `$_SERVER` global

```
if ($_SERVER['argc'] >= 3) {
  switch( $_SERVER['argv'][1] ) {
     case 'show':
        ...
        break;

     case 'search':
        ...
        break;
   }
} else {
   // no args case
}
```

On general, it's usually useful to try i.e.

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `$argv[1]` instead

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

`$argv[0]` contains the name of the script which was called

Answer (score 1):

Use $argv[1].

In UNIX model (like...C), the traditional ARGV array starts with the first binary invoked, then passes along the arguments. In PHP case, if you call your script through PHP ("php script.php") instead of hash-banging it ("./script.php"), php automatically removes itself from $argv[0].

So in your case:

```
$ cat argv.php
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    print_r($argv);
?>
$ php argv.php search
Array
(
    [0] => argv.php
    [1] => search
)
$ ./argv.php search
Array
(
    [0] => ./argv.php
    [1] => search
)
$
```